# Forward surge current - what this mean?

Tags: semiconductors

I am reading and studying data sheet of the semiconductor 1N4001 until 1N4007, by Fairchild on onsemi.com. And I can't understand this parameter "forward surge current"

My main language isn't English, should be why I can't understand this concept!

Someone can give me an idea about this parameter/concept?

Answer (score 8):

Surge current is a peak non repetitive current. One typical scenario for surge current is power supply power up, when the filtering capacitors are totally discharged (inrush current).

There are also parameters for repetitive peaks.

In Spanish these parameters are called "corriente de pico no repetitivo" for surge and "corriente de pico repetitivo" for repetitive peak

Answer (score 3):

> Maximum (peak or surge) forward current = IFSM or if(surge), the maximum peak amount of current the diode is able to conduct in forward bias mode. Again, this rating is limited by the diode junction’s thermal capacity, and is usually much higher than the average current rating due to thermal inertia (the fact that it takes a finite amount of time for the diode to reach maximum temperature for a given current). Ideally, this figure would be infinite.

Source: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-3/diode-ratings/